# /bin/sh: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nvm

I am creating a docker image for stf.installing nodejs directly using apt-get install nodejs,had many issues.So i decided to go the nvm way.but after installation RUN npm install fails
I am building the docker image with su username docker build ..

```
make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 6

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

#WORKDIR /usr/app


# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install
```

and the output

```
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/usr/local/nvm'
=> Cloning into '/usr/local/nvm'...
* (HEAD detached at v0.30.1)
  master

=> Appending source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.13.0/node-v6.13.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
Now using node v6.13.0 (npm v3.10.10)
default -> 6 (-> v6.13.0)
Now using node v6.13.0 (npm v3.10.10)
Removing intermediate container eb9cb6c46f34
 ---> eeef6bf9f0f1
Step 38/52 : ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
 ---> Running in 185bef8e530c
Removing intermediate container 185bef8e530c
 ---> 0e5bf7b1cfd9
Step 39/52 : ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 00d58493e199
Removing intermediate container 00d58493e199
 ---> 81ed9823020b
Step 40/52 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 1c7577133e24
/bin/sh: npm: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Please Help.Thanks

Ran the container and checked NPM path

```
root@69e513b99e68:/home/mobile/MobileFarmDocker#

 echo $PATH
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.13.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

root@69e513b99e68:/home/mobile/MobileFarmDocker# which npm
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.13.0/bin/npm
```

Comment: Just remove the failing step, build the image, start it with a shell and while inside the container check the $PATH and the location of npm and validate that the latter is on the path

Comment: @alex npm is part of node.js

Comment: @OlegSklyar ran the container with detach option,container was exiting without detach.mobile@admin1-desktop:~/MobileFarmDocker$ sudo docker exec -i -t 69e513b99e68 /bin/bash
root@69e513b99e68:/home/mobile/MobileFarmDocker# which npm
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.13.0/bin/npm

Comment: @OlegSklyar How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you need to create the docker image like this. I strongly suggest using one of the docker library node images: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/

Comment: (at the very least, you may find the associated docker files helpful for suggestion solutions to your issue)

Answer (score 2):

Your `$NODE_VERSION` variable has value `6` as defined in the `Dockerfile` (`ENV NODE_VERSION 6`) but it should be `6.13.0` so that the following line may work properly:

```
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

(mapping to `/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.13.0/bin`)

Otherwise, you are actually generating the following (wrong) path:

```
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6/bin
```